# startActivityForResult for capturing image via the camera returns diffrent requestcode?

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm developing an android app with the ability to attach images from the camera.
The attach button found in two different activities, and the request code that returns from the camera when finishing is different from one activity to another, here is my code:

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/aaa/temp", "temp.jpg");
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
```

**onActivityResult** the returned requestCode is **NOT** 10 but "65546" and from the other activity the requestCode is "327690" !!!

Why does the camera activity discards the "10" that I have sent when starting it??

Is it bug? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem. Create a `public static final int` in each `Activity` and use the correct one as requestCode. Also, if you are calling `startActivityForResult(...)` from a `Fragment`, try changing it with '`getActivity().startActivityForResult(...)`'

Comment: getActivity(). did the work and the return requestcode is "10" !!!!!! thank you dumazt :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually set your request and results codes from both Activities (requesting and responding) which means you need to have your own Camera-activity implementation class. You should post the code from that (Camera-Activity) class here for us to help you.

A good way to be safe with correct request/result codes as stated in other answers, is to declare public static int codeX for each request/result code and use these variables in every call.

To assist you further, here is an example on how to implement concurrent request and result codes for the two communicating activities:

- Requesting Activity

  ```
          int requestCode=1;
          int resultOk=0;

          Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Responding.class);
          startActivityForResult(intent,requestCode);
  ```
- Responding Camera-Activity

  ```
          int resultOk=0;

          Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
          // you can use this to pass your stuff to the Requesting activity
          returnIntent.putExtra("extraStuff",stuff);
          setResult(resultOk,returnIntent);
          finish();
  ```
- Requesting Activity

  ```
  int resultOk=0;

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int request, int result, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(request, result, data);
  if (result == resultok && request == requestCode) {
      //get your extra stuff from intent
      int result = data.getIntExtra("extraStuff", 0);

  } else {
      // Handle different scenarios
  }

  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

> onActivityResult the returned requestCode is NOT 10 but "65546" and from the other activity the requestCode is "327690" !!!
>
> Why does the camera activity discards the "10" that I have sent when starting it??
>
> Is it bug? Is there any workaround?

You're starting the activity from a fragment and receiving the result in the activity. That's the problem.

You need to start the activity and get the result either both in the fragment, or both in the activity. Do not mix the two.

What happens is that in the v4 support library fragments, fragment index is encoded in the top 16 bits of the request code and your request code is in the bottom 16 bits. For example, 65546 is really `1 << 16 + 10` and 327690 is `5 << 16 + 10`. This fragment index is later used to find the correct fragment to deliver the result to.